# I get a NullPointerException when opening audio

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am trying to open audio files but it doesn't work.
 I don't know if it's the OS or something else but when i was on Windows i didn't have this problem.
 I get a NullPointerException here is the error;
  I tried with an applet, bufferedInputStream, FileStream, AudioInputStream.
Nothing works.
I am on Linux.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(SoftMidiAudioFileReader.java:130)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1111)
    at com.base.engine.core.Audio.initAudio(Audio.java:29)
    at com.base.engine.core.Audio.<init>(Audio.java:18)
    at com.base.engine.game.Game.init(Game.java:43)
    at com.base.engine.core.Starter.init(Starter.java:19)
    at com.base.engine.core.Starter.run(Starter.java:43)
    at com.base.engine.core.Starter.start(Starter.java:27)
    at com.base.engine.game.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

code

```
package com.base.engine.core;


    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
    import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
    import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
    import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

    public class Audio {

        private Clip clip;
        private int fPos = 0;

        public Audio(String filename){
            initAudio(filename);
        }

        private void initAudio(String filename){
            try {
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                try {
                    AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Audio.class.getResourceAsStream("res/sounds/"+filename));
                    clip.open(stream);
                } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

        public void play(){
            clip.setFramePosition(0);
            clip.start();
            fPos = clip.getFramePosition();
        }

        public void playAt(int pos){
            clip.setFramePosition(pos);
            clip.start();
            fPos = clip.getFramePosition();
        }

        public void continuePlay(){
            clip.setFramePosition(fPos);
            clip.start();
            fPos = clip.getFramePosition();
        }

        public void stop(){
            fPos = clip.getFramePosition();
            clip.stop();
        }




    }
```

Comment: I would check the value of filename, ensure that it exists where expected (i.e. that you don't have a C:\ path).

Comment: If `res` is in the `src`, try it with a forward slash, i.e. `/res`

Comment: Well i checked the value of filename in debug mode it says the name of my file "sounds.wav" so i don't think it's that.

Comment: I tried with a forward slash too.

Comment: And is `res` in the `src`?

Comment: nope.The folders in my project folder are source, bin and res.

Comment: `res` should be in `bin`. From your IDE it should be in `src`, which will get copied to `bin` anyway (depending on the IDE). And then use `/res`

Comment: OK.i use eclipse.My res folder is a class folder do i still have to move it to bin?

Comment: Ok, put the `res` in the `src`, and it will get copied to `bin` (you don't need to worry about that). Then use `/res`. It should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If `File` exists then only go further.

```
File f = new File("D:\\folder\\file.mp3");
System.out.print(f.exists());
```

Comment: well how to check my hard disk name if i am on debian linux?

Comment: linux you can use something like `/user/folder/file.mp3`